# How to find value in array using ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working on the caller name announcer app, for this app, I stored contact in local storage and I am getting contacts value in an array. Why I am doing this because when someone calls me it takes time to find a contact. So my senior suggest me to store in local storage and when call receives it finds from local storage so that way it works fast then early. for this I did this code, please help me if possible.

I am using this plugin: [contacts](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/contacts)

```
declare var window: any;

setContacts() {
const options = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter = "";
options.multiple = true;
options.hasPhoneNumber = true;

this.contact.find(['*'], options).then((contacts) => {
    this.ArrayData = contacts;
    this.storage.set("mycontactsdata", this.ArrayData);
    console.log("stringify contact all", JSON.stringify(this.ArrayData));
});
var testobj = JSON.stringify(this.ArrayData);
localStorage.setItem("testobjdata", testobj);
}

phonecalls() {
if (window.PhoneCallTrap) {
    window.PhoneCallTrap.onCall((obj) => {
        var callObj = JSON.parse(obj),
            state = callObj.state,
            callingNumber = callObj.incomingNumber;
        if (callingNumber > 0) {
            var resultdata = localStorage.getItem("testobjdata");
            if (resultdata) {
                this.ArrayData1 = JSON.parse(resultdata);
            }
            this.ArrayData1.forEach(function (item) {
                console.log(item.displayName);
                if (item._objectInstance.phoneNumbers[0] == callingNumber) {
                    console.log("found");
                    this.contactsfoundcallingNumber = item._objectInstance.displayName;
                    console.log(this.contactsfoundcallingNumber);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
}
```

Structure of value in local storage

```
[
{ "_objectInstance": 
{ 
    "id": "1", 
    "rawId": null, 
    "displayName": "Test contact name", 
    "name": { 
        "familyName": "Test", 
        "givenName": "Test", 
        "middleName": "Test", 
        "formatted": "Test Test Test" 
    }, 
        "nickname": null, 
        "phoneNumbers": [
            { 
                "id": "56", 
                "pref": false, 
                "value": "+91 xxxxx xxxxx", 
                "type": "mobile" 
            }, 
            { 
                "id": "192394", 
                "pref": false, 
                "value": "+91xxxxxxxxxx", 
                "type": "mobile" 
            }, 
            {
                "id": "201516", 
                "pref": false, 
                "value": "+91 xxxxx xxxxx", 
                "type": "mobile" 
            }
        ], 
        "emails": null, 
        "addresses": null, 
        "ims": null, 
        "organizations": null, 
        "birthday": "xxxx-xx-xxT18:30:00.000Z", 
        "note": null, 
        "photos": [
            { 
                "id": "193840", 
                "pref": false, 
                "type": "url", 
                "value": "content://com.android.contacts/contacts/1/photo" 
            }
        ], 
        "categories": null, 
        "urls": null 
    }, "rawId": "8" 
}, 
]
```

when I use the debugger and inspect in chrome inspect using USB debug I got this error and item used in the forEach function.

```
message: "item is not defined"
stack: "ReferenceError: item is not defined↵    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost/pages-home-home-module.js:411:21), <anonymous>:1:1)↵    at http://localhost/pages-home-home-module.js:411:21↵    at Object.callbackFromNative (http://localhost/cordova.js:291:58)↵    at <anonymous>:1:9"
__proto__: Error
```

Comment: structure of value in localstorage

Comment: check now with the structure on a value in local storage

Answer (score 1):

Simply try:

```
let indexOfCallingNum = this.ArrayData1.indexOf(callingNumber);
console.log("Got it : "+JSON.stringify(this.ArrayData1[indexOfCallingNum]));
```

Comment: check what callingNumber value and number in ArrayData1 array.

Comment: callingNumber mean incoming caller number ex.+91 99999 99999 and this.ArrayData1 = JSON.parse(resultdata); here is array of object

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a problem when you getting data on storage
`var resultdata = localStorage.getItem("testobjdata");`

The above will not work , since accessing memory and grabbing data need time so `getItem()` will return a promise , To solve it you have to do it like this:

```
let resultdata = [];
localStorage.getItem("testobjdata").then(data => resultData = data);
```

please note that since javascript works with a single thread any function or any using for the variable `resultData` before `then()` will be redundunt

feel free to see [Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage) documentation